# Download a file on the client macine using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, text-files

I want to download a text file from my website to the users pc without prompting him for the location to save the file.

I have tried it using code below :

```
Response.TransmitFile("G:\Medical Reporting\Medical\Users\Vishal\Uploaded\Key.txt")
Response.End()
```

But every time I am just redirected to the new page and all the contents of the file is written there. I don't want to display the contents of the file, but I want to download the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible - it's a security issue, otherwise the world would be trying to save all sorts of files on a users machine.

If it's an intranet each user could have a shared drive on a network accessible to the web app and simply copy the file using `IO.File.Copy` method.

**Update**

To Prompt a user to download a file you can use the following code which will be fired after clicking something like a button:

this example is for an image, though you can just change the ContentType filename to suit your needs.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"; 
// this is the important bit that gives the user the prompt to save
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=yourfile.jpg"); 
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/yourfile.jpg"));
Response.End();
```

Comment: May be you are not understanding me. I want to prompt to the client that he want to save the file or not. But I don't want to prompt him where to save the file. I mean I want the file to be downloaded at the default location

Comment: That's not possible either. It's a security issue. You cannot override where a user wishes to store a file. Apart from the security issue, the server would also have NO idea of the file system of the users computer. I.E it could be Mac, PC, Linux - the first 2 have different ways of file paths.

Comment: its ok. can you tell me how to prompt the user that he wants to download a file or not? If user clicks on the save file button then what should be the code for download?

Comment: added an update to show how you can prompt for a download as requested in comment :)